# Area of a region on the surface of a prolate spheroid

Tags: integration, surfaces

Is there a general expression for the area of a region bounded by 3 great ellipses on the surface of a prolate spheroid (where a great ellipse is the intersection of the spheroid with a plane passing through its centre)?